# How to change the tile on recents app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to release my new app with flutter but when I press the recent button on my android device, the title is always <> even though I've changed the name in the manifest -> application tag.[image: screenshot]

How can I change that caption/title to my app name, also how to apply the same for IOS so I won't have to ask twice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by specifying a custom `title` argument to `MaterialApp`.

```
MaterialApp(
   title: "My Title",
   ...
)
```